# Build a vector/frame by combining regmatches results

Tags: r

I have a regular expression that parses a bunch of text, an when doing `regmatches(myText,myRegex)` it returns a `list` which looks like:

```
[[1]]
  [1] "a=1"  "b=3"  "a=9"  "c=2"  "b=4"
...
```

I'd like to build a `data.frame` or `table` - whatever suits best - to finally have something like:

```
a  b  c
1  3  2
9  4  ...
```

Is it possible to make this in a simple fashion? What are your suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not entirely clear what the general case is here but this works on the data provided.

Assuming this input:

```
x <- c("a=1", "b=3", "a=9", "c=2", "b=4")
```

split the values by the names producing `s` and massage into a data.frame:

```
s <- split(as.numeric(sub(".*=", "", x)), sub("=.*", "", x))
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(s, ts)))
```

giving:

```
  a b  c
1 1 3  2
2 9 4 NA
```

No packages needed.

Comment: nice! this is what I call "simple"! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `base R` methods

```
d1 <- read.table(text=gsub("[[:punct:]]", " " , unlist(lst)))
d2 <- transform(d1, indx=ave(seq_along(V1), V1, FUN=seq_along))
res <- reshape(d2, timevar='V1', idvar='indx', direction='wide')[,-1]
colnames(res) <- gsub(".*\\.", "", colnames(res))
res
#  a  b  c
#1 1  3  2
#3 9  4  2
#6 4  5 NA
#9 9 NA NA
```

Or using `dcast` from `reshape2` on `d2`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(d2,indx~V1, value.var='V2')[,-1]
#  a  b  c
#1 1  3  2
#2 9  4  2
#3 4  5 NA
#4 9 NA NA
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(c('a=1', 'b=3', 'a=9', 'c=2', 'b=4'), 
                       c('a=4', 'c=2', 'b=5', 'a=9'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of extraction task a little simpler.

```
x <- c("a=1", "b=3", "a=9", "c=2", "b=4", "a=2")
```

First extract the names and values from the strings.

```
library(rex)

matches <- re_matches(x,
  rex(
    capture(name="name", letter),
    "=",
    capture(name="value", digit)
    ))
#>  name value
#>1    a     1
#>2    b     3
#>3    a     9
#>4    c     2
#>5    b     4
#>6    a     2
```

Then tally the groups using `split()`.

```
groups <- split(as.numeric(matches$value), matches$name)
#>$a
#>[1] 1 9 2
#>
#>$b
#>[1] 3 4
#>
#>$c
#>[1] 2
```

If we try to convert directly to a data.frame from `split()` the groups with fewer members will have their members recycled rather than `NA`, so instead explicitly fill with `NA`.

```
largest_group <- max(sapply(groups, length))
#>[1] 3

groups <- lapply(groups, function(group) {
  if (length(group) < largest_group) {
    group[largest_group] <- NA
  }
  group
})
#>$a
#>[1] 1 9 2
#>
#>$b
#>[1]  3  4 NA
#>
#>$c
#>[1]  2 NA NA
```

Finally we can create the data.frame

```
do.call('data.frame', groups)
#>  a  b  c
#>1 1  3  2
#>2 9  4 NA
#>3 2 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using tools from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast.data.table(                  ## Makes the long data wide
  getanID(                         ## Adds an ID variable for dcast
    ## create a single column data.table and split it by the "="
    cSplit(as.data.table(unlist(lst)), "V1", "="), "V1_1"), 
  .id ~ V1_1, value.var = "V1_2")
#    .id a  b  c
# 1:   1 1  3  2
# 2:   2 9  4  2
# 3:   3 4  5 NA
# 4:   4 9 NA NA
```

---

This uses @akrun's sample data:

```
lst <- list(c('a=1', 'b=3', 'a=9', 'c=2', 'b=4'), 
            c('a=4', 'c=2', 'b=5', 'a=9'))
```